Google Books API giving responce with "totalItems": 0 (books/v1/volumes?q=...)
I tried accessing books.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flowers on Postman, Java Application, OAuth Playground, via browser and by APIs Explorer.
OAuth Playground returns a normal response with a totalItems = 3040 and futher information;
But others response with:
{
    "kind": "books#volumes",
    "totalItems": 0
}

Just to clarify, if GET-request send to books/v1/volumes/xcx1jgEACAAJ , response is positive.
What am i missing?
Not sure how's this achievable in Java (other than adding key to url) but in postman i saved my credentials from Google Cloud. That's... Everything that came into my mind (and i've generated it with different credentials several times, rrly didn't worked out). I believe, given request does not requires any user info since it's public.

If anybody wonders, the problem is that i am from Belarus! After turning on vpn, the response was positive.
I am quitting internet with this one rrly т.т
